# Why is my solution incorrect, where am I missing a concept?

Tags: calculus, integration

We have a problem from Khan Academy:
[image]

To solve it I had used online integral calculator(https://www.integral-calculator.com/)
in order to solve the integral, and than evaluated the integral at 5.
Because: $\frac{d(Height)}{d(Time)} = r(t)$ From the problem.

Differentiating it gives

$Height = \int(r(t)dt$

Which as far as I understand should be correct if we evaluate this at 5 and add inital 20 centimeters. But, this is not the correct answer.

After looking at the solution it should be like that:
[image]

[image]

Can someone explain, why mine is incorrect

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think this is different from your solution?

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5B10*Sqrt%5B1-Cos%5B+0.5+x%5D%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C5%7D%5D%2B20) seems to get the same answer as Khan academy. Are you sure you entered the function into the integral calculator correctly?

Comment: "$Height = \int r(t) dt$ which as far as I understand should be correct if we evaluate this at 5 and add inital 20 centimeters." Yes if $\int r(t)dt$ is meant as a shorthand for  $\int_0^t r(t')dt' = R(t) - R(0)$. However, just evaluating any antiderivative of $r(t)$ at 5 won't do, because of the constant of integration. You need to subtract off its value at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

To get the solution obtained by Khan Academy, you need to find the function for depth as you have done:

$f(t) = -5*$$2^\frac {7}{2}$$*cos(\frac {t}{4})$

Once you do this, substitute t=5 to get -17.837, then t=0 to get -56.569.
-17.837- (-56.569) = 38.731

Adding the 20cm you get the answer obtained by Khan Academy.

Interestingly, if you use the definite integral option on that online calculator you obtain an approximation of 45.842 but this is due to the calculator's engine which computes the antiderivative in terms of complex numbers.

Your method appears correct so I suspect the issue may be with how you calculated $f(t)$.

Comment: I hope this helps, let me know if it doesn't though :)

Comment: Hello, Johnson, no I have used the same formula as you for f. The problem is not how they calculated, I understand it. What I'm interested in is: "Why can't we just evaluate at 5?" Wouldn't that give the height at 5, plus 20 which is from before? 
Thanks

Comment: It is important to note that at t=0, f(0) does not equal 0. In a real world context I understand this doesn’t seem to make sense but you can’t ignore it either way. You could think of this negative value as how much snow melts away if you like. So by taking into account the negative values you are considering the snow that falles on the surface and taking away how much melts away

Comment: Thanks, but still why can't we just evaluate at 5?

Comment: Because as you have in your formula above, it is f(5) - f(0) and f(0) does not equal zero.